# putting "On Change" listener on jFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, events, listen, jformattedtextfield

I have a jFormattedTextField in my program and I need to update a jLabel's text when jFormattedTextField value has been changed validly.
Actually jFormattedTextField gets a number and jLabel displays diffrence between this number and another number.
I currently do this by listenning to "FocusLost" event of jFormatted text.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

register a PropertyChangeListener for the property "value" to the formattedField

```
    PropertyChangeListener l = new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String text = evt.getNewValue() != null ? evt.getNewValue().toString() : "";
            label.setText(evt.getNewValue());
        }
    };
    formattedTextField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", l);
```

Do not use DocumentListener nor FocusListener: the former is notified too often (on every keytyped, before parsing happened) the latter is too brittle.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't get called often enough.  Seems to work like I'd expect a FocusListener.  But the DocumentListener gets called even when simply entering the field.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use a `javax.swing.event.DocumentListener` that you attache to the text field. Then, as the user types, the label can be updated.

I don't remember the exact sequence, but the listener's `insertUpdate()` may be called before the formatted text field is validated. So, you may also need to check for valid numbers in your listener too.